Comparing Closed-form to Numerical Integral Result
When I numerically calculate this integral
  NIntegrate[(1/2)*Log[1 + Sin[x]]^2, {x, 0, Pi}]

The result is $0.416217488896557$ and I verified it using another tool.
However, when I use
  Integrate[(1/2)*Log[1 + Sin[x]]^2, {x, 0, Pi}]

The result is
$$\frac{1}{48} \left(-96 C \log (2)+i \left(-192 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+105 \zeta (3)+4 \log ^3(2)\right)+7 \pi ^3-24 \pi  \log ^2(2)-5 i \pi ^2 \log (2)\right)$$
Numerically, this evaluates to $4.777566543250842 -2.9605947323337506\times 10^{-16} i$
Am I doing something wrong?
I am using Mathematica 14.0.0.0 on an x86, 64-bit, Windows 10 machine.
Update I tried it on Mathematica 12.2.0.0 and it left the integral unevaluated and I expected this because I couldn't imagine it would have a closed-form solution.

This is weird. What is that $C$ supposed to represent in your result? I get the correct result in v14.0 (Win). Can you please try your code again on a fresh kernel (use Quit[]) to remove any possible effects of caching?

@Domen: From a fresh kernel, resolves the problem $$\frac{1}{48} \left(2 i \left(-192 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)+105 \zeta (3)+4 \log ^3(2)\right)-7 \pi ^3+12 \pi  \log ^2(2)-10 i \pi ^2 \log (2)\right)$$ Using Chop, that gives the correct result. I did the same thing earlier by restarting Mathematica, ut the issue persisted.

Good! These things happen ... Please let us know if you can reproduce this issue again (ie. find a sequence of integrations that lead to the wrong result). In this case, it can then be further analyzed or reported to the WRI as a "bug".

@Domen: Just FYI - Please see the latest answer - another person was able to see what I saw and provided a nice workaround.

If you do
p = Integrate[(1/2)*Log[1 + Sin[x]]^2, x]
Limit[p, x -> \[Pi], Direction -> "FromBelow"] - 
Limit[p, x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] // FullSimplify

you get
(7*Pi^3)/24 + Pi*Log[2]^2 - 
4*I*(PolyLog[3, 1 - I] - PolyLog[3, 1 + I])]

which gives the same result as NIntegrate.

Thanks - in a new iteration, after restarting the kernel, it produces the correct results - which I had done earlier. The problem persisted but in this round it worked.

For me, like the OP's original result,
Integrate[(1/2)*Log[1 + Sin[x]]^2, {x, 0, Pi}]

yields
(*
1/48 (7 \[Pi]^3 - 96 Catalan Log[2] - 5 I \[Pi]^2 Log[2] - 
   24 \[Pi] Log[2]^2 + 
   I (4 Log[2]^3 - 192 PolyLog[3, 1/2 + I/2] + 105 Zeta[3]))
*)

But
Integrate[(1/2)*Log[1 + Sin[x]]^2, {x, 0, Pi/2, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < x < Pi]

yields
(*
1/48 (-7 \[Pi]^3 - 10 I \[Pi]^2 Log[2] + 12 \[Pi] Log[2]^2 + 
   2 I (4 Log[2]^3 - 192 PolyLog[3, 1/2 + I/2] + 105 Zeta[3]))
*)

N[%, 80]
(*
0.416217488896552119403646053625517279786339361782973377550142 + 0.*10^-61 I
*)

which agrees with the numerical integration.
I've found that sometimes specifying the integration path helps, as it does in this case.

Thanks for showing that you got the same thing as I did as I felt I had not done anything to cause an errant result. What is even stranger is that using a fresh kernel then generated the correct result. I like your approach of providing as much input as possible to try and avoid these things. +1.
